# Xamarin Android Drag and Drop ListView

Tags: c#, android, listview, drag-and-drop, xamarin

I'm trying to get a drag and drop ListView working in my project. I'm mimicking this project: http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/ListViewDraggingAnimation.zip, explained in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q. I basically just did my best to translate it to C#.

It only sort of works. It's very buggy. After the long press, I can drag the row around. When I drag a bottom row to the row above it, the row below blinks rapidly between the content of the two rows as if they are switching back and forth over and over. They don't ever really switch or update properly.

The other issue is when I let go of the row I'm dragging, I get a NullPointerException on `hoverViewAnimator.Start()`. I can't step into this method so it's difficult to determine what's null.

Here is the code relevant to the null exception:

```
private void touchEventsEnded()
{
    View mobileView = getViewForID(mMobileItemId);
    if (mCellIsMobile || mIsWaitingForScrollFinish)
    {
        mCellIsMobile = false;
        mIsWaitingForScrollFinish = false;
        mIsMobileScrolling = false;
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

        if (mScrollState != (int)ScrollState.Idle)
        {
            mIsWaitingForScrollFinish = true;
            return;
        }

        mHoverCellCurrentBounds.OffsetTo(mHoverCellOriginalBounds.Left, mobileView.Top);

        ObjectAnimator hoverViewAnimator = ObjectAnimator.OfObject(mHoverCell, "bounds", new sBoundEvaluator(), mHoverCellCurrentBounds);

        hoverViewAnimator.Update += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Invalidate();
        };
        hoverViewAnimator.AnimationStart += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Enabled = false;
        };
        hoverViewAnimator.AnimationEnd += (sender, e) =>
        {
            mAboveItemId = INVALID_ID;
            mMobileItemId = INVALID_ID;
            mBelowItemId = INVALID_ID;
            mobileView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            mHoverCell = null;
            Enabled = true;
            Invalidate();
        };

        hoverViewAnimator.Start(); // null pointer exception thrown here
    }
    else
        touchEventsCancelled();
}
```

If you're brave enough to go through more of my code, here is the rest of it:

DragableListView.cs: http://pastebin.com/bVQcY7Zj

IDragableAdapter.cs: http://pastebin.com/LGz0swDr

BaseDragableAdapter.cs: http://pastebin.com/n15bc56K

Comment: I also partially ported that DevBytes tutorial to C# for use with a Xamarin Android project. You can check it out here: https://github.com/pnavk/DraggableListView. Instead of using the ViewTreeObserver's PreDraw event. I did the translation-y animation first and then on the Object Animator's AnimationEnd event, I update the dataset.